# C++: Initialization of member variables

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, member-initialization, ctor-initializer

I have a confusion on class member variable initialization.

Suppose in my .h file is:

```
class Test {

int int_var_1;
float float_var_2;

public:
       Test();
}
```

My .cpp would be:

```
Test::Test() : int_var_1(100), float_var_2(1.5f) {}
```

Now when I instantiate a class the variables get initialized to 100 and 1.5.

But if that is all I'm doing in my constructor, I can do the following in my .cpp:

```
int Test::int_var_1 = 100;
float Test::float_var_2 = 1.5f;
```

I'm confused as to the difference between initializing the variables in constructors or with the resolution operator.

Does this way of initializing variables outside constructor with scope resolution only apply to static variables or is there a way it can be done for normal variables too?

Comment: The second method won't work because there's no instance and these are instance variables - they need an instance. Comparing that to C++11 in-class initialization (`class C {int i = 5;}`), this actually just fills 5 in where an initialization would otherwise take place. It doesn't actually initialize anything earlier.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot substitute one for the other. If the member variables are not static, you have to use the initialization list (or the constructor body, but the initialization list is better suited)<sup>*</sup>. If the member variables are static, then you must initialize them in the definition with the syntax in the second block.

<sup>*</sup> Als correctly points out that in C++11 you can also provide an initializer in the declaration for non-static member variables:

```
class test {
   int data = 5;
};
```

Will have `data(5)` implicitly added to any initialization list where `data` is not explicitly mentioned (including an implicitly defined default constructor)

Comment: C++11 allows In-place Initialization for static members(C++11 §9.4.2.3)

Comment: @Als: C++11 allows for in-place initialization of **non**-static members, and the syntax would not be that of the second example, but rather in the declaration of the member.

Comment: True that, its **non-static** members and not **static** members, just wanted to add that for completeness.

Comment: @Als: By the way, the reference you provided is for yet another case that I did not mention: `static const` members of integral type or `constexpr` static variables of literal types can also be initialized in the class declaration: `struct S { static const int i = 10; };` (although the definition is still required if the variable is *odr-used*. Noted the *non-static* case in the answer.

Comment: Yes, Indeed.The reference for the *non-static* case is §12.6.2.8 and ofcourse the +1 :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Thank you. Think I got it now. If its a non-static member variables I need must use the constructor, but if its a static variable, then I use the second method. Using the scope operator. That means even static variables are not allowed to be initialized in-class?

Comment: @madu: The exact rules are not that simple, and they have become more complex in C++11. Inside the class definition you can provide value to non-static member functions (C++11 only), or `static const` variables of integral types (C++03), or `constexpr` of literal types (C++11): `struct test { int a = 5; int b; test() : b(10) {} static const int k = 15; static constexpr double d = 10.5; static int s; }; int test::s = 20;`

Comment: Thank you David for that explanation.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas  To be honest with you I think the new rules are far SIMPLER than C++03.  I think they HAVE muddied up the clarity of the Constructor itself though.  To a large degree they have removed its purpose, or certainly the point of supplying a custom one for your class. Although equally I have also read advice to only override the default constructor when you absolutely have to, so perhaps this helps towards that end too.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the first method when you are initializing non-static `const` variables (at the constructor). That is the only way you can modify those kinds of member variables (unless you are using C++11).

Static member variables can be initialized by using proper scope resolution operators (outside the class).

Comment: Isn't EVERYONE using C++11 now - after all who can live without range-based for loops???  Humour aside - and I actually do like the new for loops - I think it is important to teach to the newest standard.  Especially when so much work has gone in to improving ease-of-use.  We should all be pushing C++11 as hard as possible, otherwise C# is going to gain even more ground and we C++ programmers will start heading in the direction of Perl users, post-Python.  And I REALLY like Perl as well!!!

Comment: @GemmanAster Nope, especially for older SDKs which can't use C++11 for various reasons.

Comment: You make a good point - but those situations must still be considered 'edge cases'.  C++11 really has brought so much that is positive to the language while also eliminating a number of annoying idiosyncrasies that I really cannot think of a good reason not to adopt it - unless as you say there is a shortcoming in an SDK for a very specific platform.