# does not have class type C++

Tags: c++

This is one class from my program! When I'm trying to compile the whole program, I get an error message like this:

> main.cpp:174: error: '((Scene*)this)->Scene::lake' does not have class type

The source

```
class Scene
{
    int L,Dist;
    Background back ;
    Lake lake(int L);
    IceSkater iceskater(int Dist);
public :
    Scene(int L, int Dist)
    {
        cout<<"Scene was just created"<<endl;
    }

    ~Scene()
    {
        cout<<"Scene is about to be destroyed !"<<endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: lake is a method, not a variable

Lake lake(int L);

lake.light_up(); //This not make sense

Comment: Lake is a class and I'n trying to create her object lake in class scene

Comment: Sure is a class, but lake(in lowcase) is a method, and you're tryng to call a method of that object, this line is wrong,  lake.light_up();

Comment: As a heads up to people having this error in a different situation: I encountered this when converting a `QVariant` type to an `std::string` like this: `x.toString.toStringStd()`. I forgot the `()` at the end of `x.toString()`. This cost me quite a few hairs on my head.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your problem is in the following line:

```
Lake lake(int L);
```

If you're just trying to declare a `Lake` object then you probably want to remove the `(int L)`.  What you have there is declaring a function `lake` that returns a `Lake` and accepts an `int` as a parameter.

If you're trying to pass in L when constructing your `lake` object, then I think you want your code to look like this:

```
class Scene
{
    int L,Dist;
    Background back ;
    Lake lake;
    IceSkater iceskater;
public :
    Scene(int L, int Dist) :
        L(L),     
        Dist(Dist),
        lake(L),
        iceskater(Dist)
    {
        cout<<"Scene was just created"<<endl;
    }
.....
```

Notice the 4 lines added to your constructor.  This is called member initialization, and its how you construct member variables.  Read more about it in this [faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html).  Or some other tidbits I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7666867/507606) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170160/c-initialization-of-member-variables).

Answer (score 3):

You declare `lake` as a method that takes one argument and returns a `Lake`. You then try and call a method on it via `lake.light_up()`. This causes the error you observe.

To solve the problem, you either need to declare `lake` to be a variable, e.g. `Lake lake;`, or you need to stop trying to call a method on it.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared (but never defined) `lake` as a member function of Scene:

```
class Scene
{
    // ...
    Lake lake(int L);
```

But then in `plot`, you try to use `lake` as if it were a variable:

```
int plot()
{
    lake.light_up();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line `Lake lake(int L);` with `Lake lake= Lake(L);`
or with this: `Lake lake{L};`